Directory listing URLs, serving webdav files from different URI
I want to set up a simple webdav server with nginx, that I can access using IP address to serve files when requesting: http://IP/webdav/.
I did changed root directory to required one and I can see the listing of the folder when accessing a resource.
But if I try to click on any of the files in the list, they have link of the type: http://IP/filename
How to list the directory, so that listed files will be linked instead as: http://IP/webdav/filename ?
Nginx config:
server{
listen 80;
root /path/to/root/folder/

location /webdav/ {
  dav_methods ...
  dav_ext_methods ...
  autoindex on;
}


}

The files are actually physically located in /path/to/root/folder/webdav/
